# How to add audio to an mp4 file created with a SinkWriter?

Tags: c++, audio, ms-media-foundation

I want to make an mp4 file as a sink writer.
The video could be made by providing samples from msdn, but the audio could not be created.
So I did a search and got this source. But this source did not hear any audio either.
Is this a bad source? So where is the wrong part?

Here is search code:

```
//Audio constants
const GUID  AUDIO_MAJOR_TYPE = MFMediaType_Audio;           //for audio treatment
const GUID      AUDIO_ENCODING_FORMAT = MFAudioFormat_AAC;      //encoding format (output)
const GUID      AUDIO_INPUT_FORMAT = MFAudioFormat_PCM;     //input format
const UINT32    AUDIO_SAMPLES_PER_SECOND = 44100;           //samples per second
const UINT32    AUDIO_AVG_BYTES_PER_SECOND = 16000;         //average bytes per second
const UINT32    AUDIO_NUM_CHANNELS = 1;                     //MONO or STEREO
const UINT32    AUDIO_BITS_PER_SAMPLE = 16;                 //bits per sample
const UINT32    AUDIO_ONE_SECOND = 10;                      //quantity of buffers per second
const UINT32    AUDIO_BUFFER_LENGTH = AUDIO_BITS_PER_SAMPLE / 8 * AUDIO_NUM_CHANNELS * AUDIO_SAMPLES_PER_SECOND;                                                    //max. buffer size
const LONGLONG  AUDIO_SAMPLE_DURATION = 10000000;           //sample duration


//Creation of a template to release pointers
template <class T> void SafeRelease(T **ppT)
{
    if (*ppT)
    {
        (*ppT)->Release();
        *ppT = NULL;
    }
}


//Creation of the Byte Stream
IMFByteStream* CreateFileByteStream(LPCWSTR FileName)
{
    //create file byte stream
    IMFByteStream *pByteStream = NULL;

    HRESULT hr = MFCreateFile(MF_ACCESSMODE_WRITE, MF_OPENMODE_DELETE_IF_EXIST, MF_FILEFLAGS_NONE, FileName, &pByteStream);

    if (FAILED(hr))
        pByteStream = NULL;

    return pByteStream;
}


//Creation of the Video profile (H264)
IMFMediaType* CreateVideoProfile()


//Creation of the Audio profile (AAC)
IMFMediaType* CreateAudioProfile()
{
    IMFMediaType *pMediaType = NULL;

    HRESULT hr = MFCreateMediaType(&pMediaType);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pMediaType->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, AUDIO_MAJOR_TYPE);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pMediaType->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, AUDIO_ENCODING_FORMAT);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_BITS_PER_SAMPLE, AUDIO_BITS_PER_SAMPLE);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_SAMPLES_PER_SECOND, AUDIO_SAMPLES_PER_SECOND);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_NUM_CHANNELS, AUDIO_NUM_CHANNELS);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_AVG_BYTES_PER_SECOND, AUDIO_AVG_BYTES_PER_SECOND);
    }

    if (FAILED(hr))
        pMediaType = NULL;

    return pMediaType;
}


//Create an aggregate source (both audio and video)
IMFMediaSource* CreateAggregatedSource(IMFMediaSource *pSource1, IMFMediaSource *pSource2, IMFMediaSource *pAggSource)
{
    pAggSource = NULL;
    IMFCollection *pCollection = NULL;

    HRESULT hr = MFCreateCollection(&pCollection);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pCollection->AddElement(pSource1);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pCollection->AddElement(pSource2);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = MFCreateAggregateSource(pCollection, &pAggSource);
    }

    SafeRelease(&pCollection);

    if (FAILED(hr))
        pAggSource = NULL;

    return pAggSource;
}


//Creation of the MPEG-4 MediaSink
IMFMediaSink* CreateMediaSink(IMFByteStream *pByteStream, IMFMediaType *pVideoMediaType, IMFMediaType *pAudioMediaType)
{
    IMFMediaSink *pMediaSink = NULL;
    DWORD pdwCharac = NULL;
    DWORD pdwStreamCount = NULL;

    HRESULT hr = MFCreateMPEG4MediaSink(pByteStream, pVideoMediaType, pAudioMediaType, &pMediaSink);

    //// DEBUG ////
    pMediaSink->GetCharacteristics(&pdwCharac);
    pMediaSink->GetStreamSinkCount(&pdwStreamCount);

    if (FAILED(hr))
        pMediaSink = NULL; 

    return pMediaSink;
}


IMFAttributes* CreateAttributesForSinkWriter()
{
    IMFAttributes *pMFAttributes = NULL;

    HRESULT hr = MFCreateAttributes(&pMFAttributes, 100);

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pMFAttributes->SetGUID(MF_TRANSCODE_CONTAINERTYPE, MFTranscodeContainerType_MPEG4);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pMFAttributes->SetUINT32(MF_READWRITE_ENABLE_HARDWARE_TRANSFORMS, FALSE); //no hardware encoding
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pMFAttributes->SetUINT32(MF_READWRITE_DISABLE_CONVERTERS, FALSE); //enable converting formats
    }

    if (FAILED(hr))
        pMFAttributes = NULL;

    return pMFAttributes;
}


//Initialization of the Video SinkWriter...
HRESULT InitializeSinkWriterVideo(IMFSinkWriter **ppWriter, DWORD *pStreamIndex, IMFMediaSink *pMediaSink)


//Initialization of the Audio SinkWriter...
HRESULT InitializeSinkWriterAudio(IMFSinkWriter **ppWriter, DWORD *pStreamIndex, IMFMediaSink *pMediaSink)
{
    *ppWriter = NULL;
    *pStreamIndex = NULL;

    IMFSinkWriter  *pSinkWriter = NULL;
    IMFMediaType *pMediaTypeOut = NULL;
    IMFMediaType *pMediaTypeIn = NULL;
    IMFAttributes    *pAttrib = NULL;
    DWORD      streamIndex = 1;

    HRESULT hr = MFCreateSinkWriterFromMediaSink(pMediaSink, NULL, &pSinkWriter);

    //input : audio
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = MFCreateMediaType(&pMediaTypeIn);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pMediaTypeIn->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, AUDIO_MAJOR_TYPE);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pMediaTypeIn->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, AUDIO_INPUT_FORMAT);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pMediaTypeIn->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_BITS_PER_SAMPLE, AUDIO_BITS_PER_SAMPLE);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pMediaTypeIn->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_SAMPLES_PER_SECOND, AUDIO_SAMPLES_PER_SECOND);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pMediaTypeIn->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_NUM_CHANNELS, AUDIO_NUM_CHANNELS);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pSinkWriter->SetInputMediaType(streamIndex, pMediaTypeIn, NULL);
    }

    //Tell the Audio SinkWriter to begin data treatment
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pSinkWriter->BeginWriting();
    }

    //Possible error codes
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        if (hr == MF_E_INVALIDMEDIATYPE)
            UINT32 uiShutDown = 0;

        if (hr == MF_E_INVALIDSTREAMNUMBER)
            UINT32 uiShutDown = 1;

        if (hr == MF_E_TOPO_CODEC_NOT_FOUND)
            UINT32 uiShutDown = 2;
    }

    //Returns the pointer of the caller
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        *ppWriter = pSinkWriter;
        (*ppWriter)->AddRef();
        *pStreamIndex = streamIndex;
    }

    //Release pointers
    SafeRelease(&pSinkWriter);
    SafeRelease(&pMediaTypeOut);
    SafeRelease(&pMediaTypeIn);
    SafeRelease(&pAttrib);

    return hr;
}


//Write a video frame
HRESULT WriteVideoFrame(IMFSinkWriter *pWriter, DWORD streamIndex, const LONGLONG& rtStart, const LONGLONG& rtDuration)


//Write an audio packet
HRESULT WriteAudioPacket(IMFSinkWriter *pWriter, DWORD streamIndex, const LONGLONG& rtStart, const LONGLONG& rtDuration, UINT32 Quantity)
{
    IMFSample       *pSample = NULL;
    IMFMediaBuffer  *pBuffer = NULL;

    const DWORD cbBuffer = Quantity * 2;

    BYTE *pData = NULL;


    //Create a new memory buffer, whose max. size is cbBuffer (QuantityOfSamplesPerVideoFrame * 2 Bytes)
    HRESULT hr = MFCreateMemoryBuffer(cbBuffer, &pBuffer);

    //Lock the buffer and copy the audio packet to the buffer
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pBuffer->Lock(&pData, NULL, NULL);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        for (DWORD n = 0; n < cbBuffer; n++)
        {
            pData[n] = (BYTE)(rand() & 0xFF);   //generation of random noise
        }
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pBuffer->Unlock();
    }

    // Set the data length of the buffer
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pBuffer->SetCurrentLength(cbBuffer);
    }

    //Create a media sample and add the buffer to the sample
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = MFCreateSample(&pSample);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pSample->AddBuffer(pBuffer);
    }

    //Set the time stamp and the duration
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pSample->SetSampleTime(rtStart);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pSample->SetSampleDuration(rtDuration);
    }

    //Send the sample to the Sink Writer
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pWriter->WriteSample(streamIndex, pSample);
    }

    //Release pointers
    SafeRelease(&pSample);
    SafeRelease(&pBuffer);

    return hr;
}


// MAIN FUNCTION
void main()
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    IMFByteStream           *spByteStream = NULL;
    IMFMediaSink            *pMediaSink = NULL;
    IMFSinkWriter           *spSinkWriterVid = NULL;
    IMFSinkWriter           *spSinkWriterAud = NULL;
    IMFMediaType            *spVideo = NULL;
    IMFMediaType            *spAudio = NULL;
    //IMFMediaEventGenerator    *spMFMediaEvtGene = NULL;
    //IMFMediaEvent         *spMFMediaEvent = NULL;
    IMFAttributes           *spAttrib = NULL;

    DWORD                   sindexVid = 0, sindexAud = 0, j = 0;

    LPCWSTR str = L"outputfile.mp4";

    hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = MFStartup(MF_VERSION);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            spByteStream = CreateFileByteStream(str);
            if (spByteStream != NULL)
            {
                spVideo = CreateVideoProfile();
            }
            if (spVideo != NULL)
            {
                spAudio = CreateAudioProfile();
            }
            if (spAudio != NULL)
            {
                pMediaSink = CreateMediaSink(spByteStream, spVideo, spAudio);
            }

            if (pMediaSink != NULL)
            {
                hr = InitializeSinkWriterVideo(&spSinkWriterVid, &sindexVid, pMediaSink);
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    LONGLONG rtStartVid = 0;
                    UINT64 rtDurationVid = 0;

                    /********************************************************
                    *                       VIDEO PART               *
                    ********************************************************/

                    //Calculate the average time per frame, for video
                    //MFFrameRateToAverageTimePerFrame(VIDEO_FPS, 1, &rtDurationVid);

                    //loop to treat all the pictures
                    for (DWORD i = 0; i < VIDEO_FRAME_COUNT; ++i, ++j)
                    {
                        //Picture pixels
                        for (DWORD k = 0; k < VIDEO_PELS; k++)
                        {
                            if (j>255)
                                j = 0;

                            videoFrameBuffer[k] = ((j << 16) & 0x00FF0000) | ((j << 8) & 0x0000FF00) | (j & 0x000000FF);
                        }
                        hr = WriteVideoFrame(spSinkWriterVid, sindexVid, rtStartVid, rtDurationVid);

                        if (FAILED(hr))
                        {
                            break;
                        }

                        //Update the time stamp value
                        rtStartVid += rtDurationVid;
                    }

                    //Finalization of writing with the Video SinkWriter
                    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                    {
                        hr = spSinkWriterVid->Finalize();
                    }
                }
            }

            SafeRelease(&spVideo);
            SafeRelease(&spSinkWriterVid);

            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                hr = InitializeSinkWriterAudio(&spSinkWriterAud, &sindexAud, pMediaSink);
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    LONGLONG rtStartAud = 0;
                    UINT64 rtDurationAud;
                    double QtyAudioSamplesPerVideoFrame = 0;

                    //Calculate the approximate quantity of samples, according to a video frame duration
                    //44100 Hz -> 1 s
                    //????? Hz -> 0.04 s (= 40 ms = one video frame duration)
                    if (VIDEO_FPS != 0)
                        QtyAudioSamplesPerVideoFrame = ((double)AUDIO_SAMPLES_PER_SECOND / (double)VIDEO_FPS);
                    else
                        QtyAudioSamplesPerVideoFrame = 0;

                    MFFrameRateToAverageTimePerFrame(VIDEO_FPS, 1, &rtDurationAud); //we treat the same duration as the video
                    //it means that we will treat N audio packets for the last of one picture (=40 ms)

                    //loop to treat all the audio packets
                    if (rtDurationAud != 0)
                    {
                        for (DWORD i = 0; i < VIDEO_FRAME_COUNT; ++i)
                        {
                            //Audio packets
                            hr = WriteAudioPacket(spSinkWriterAud, sindexAud, rtStartAud, rtDurationAud, (UINT32)QtyAudioSamplesPerVideoFrame);

                            if (FAILED(hr))
                            {
                                break;
                            }

                            //Update the time stamp value
                            rtStartAud += rtDurationAud;
                        }

                        //Finalization of writing with the Audio SinkWriter
                        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                        {
                            hr = spSinkWriterAud->Finalize();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            //Release pointers
            SafeRelease(&spByteStream);
            SafeRelease(&spAudio);
            SafeRelease(&spSinkWriterAud);
            SafeRelease(&spAttrib);

            //Shutdown the MediaSink (not done by the SinkWriter)
            pMediaSink->Shutdown();
            SafeRelease(&pMediaSink);
        }

        //Shutdown MediaFoundation
        MFShutdown();
        CoUninitialize();
    }

    //CDialog::OnOK();
}
```

Reference: [How to add audio data to a video file created by a SinkWriter ?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/110456dc-b7fb-479c-817c-bad5028e4102/how-to-add-audio-data-to-a-video-file-created-by-a-sinkwriter-?forum=mediafoundationdevelopment)  on MSDN Forums

Answer (score 1):

On existing `IMFSinkWriter` you already have for video (e.g. using MSDN tutorial code) you call `AddStream` and `SetInputMediaType` initializing additional stream for audio, resulting in audio track in produced MP4 file. You obtain a separate stream index for audio, which you are to use in consequent calls. Similar to `WriteSample` for video, you use `WriteSample` for audio with respective stream index and add audio data for encoding/writing in the main loop of your application.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I can not understand the answer. I am using `WriteSample` in this code, but I can not hear music. What parts of this code should I fix?

Comment: Your code cannot be executed, you don't post error codes, if any, you don't post output you get. The code is about (very roughly) right, but there is a severe problem with your code that you have two sink writer instances (`spSinkWriterAud` and `spSinkWriterVid`) while you need just one. You should use single sink writer along the lines I mentioned above.